# merge two lists and join them accordingly with a seperator in python

Tags: python, list

I'm a bit new to python.

how do i merge two lists (both strings) and join them accordingly in python?

Given the following input:

```
lista=['1','2','3']
listb=['a','b','c']
```

I would like the following output:

```
['1|a','2|b','3|c']
```

Comment: Or, at least the output needs to be a string. The `|` symbol doesn't work like that in Python. Alternatively, you can make a dictionary that has `lista` elements as keys and `listb` elements as entries. If you do want to go the dictionary route, just do: `my_dictionary = dict(zip(lista, listb))`

Comment: @jterrace yes they're both strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you actually meant to use strings, this should work:

```
>>> lista=[1,2,3]
>>> listb=['a','b','c']
>>> ["%s|%s" % (a,b) for a,b in zip(lista, listb)]
['1|a', '2|b', '3|c']
```

Answer (score 3):

This only works if both your lists contain strings.  Otherwise use one of the formatting string solutions (e.g. `%s|%s`).

```
map('|'.join, zip(lista, listb))
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are generally more readable, but the join operation is the nicest way to make this scale happily for any number of lists, and reads well, so I'd also present this amalgamation of the other answers:

```
>>>lista=['1','2','3']
>>>listb=['a','b','c']
>>>["|".join(items) for items in zip(lista, listb)]
['1|a', '2|b', '3|c']
```

Comment: How to to represent items if they are integers instead of just string in lista. because if I try lista = [1, 2, 3] I'm getting type error: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: You need to make a string from your integer - `str.join()` expects strings to join, and you are giving it integers. Simply calling `str(i)` on all of your integers will work. E.g: `["|".join(items) for items in zip(map(str, listints), liststrings)]`

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something more elegant than

```
map(lambda(x,y): "%s|%s" % (x,y), zip(lista, listb))
```